# Using Metal thumb tacks to trigger events

Tags: basic

I am new and curious to electronics, 
The below video shows a circuit bent keyboard using a keyboard made of thumb tacks to control the note input. I would love to know how this was done.

The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7G_68mkrs0

Extra information and build notes: https://imgur.com/a/qOT5Y

Is he using the tacks to complete the circuit somehow?
Is he using his fingers to change the resistance, I have no clue.

Thank you, any help would be passively appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He uses the thumb tacks to close a simple button circuit. The tracks are soldered to the individual button inputs.

Then he uses a wire connected to the common terminal (likely common ground) to "press" the buttons by sliding the over the tacks.

You can see the tack wiring on imgur about halfway down the page and the way he presses the keys at 6:40 in the video. You can see the black wire between his index and middle fingers.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would up vote your comment if I had enough reputation to do so.